# Converting a dataframe to a dictionary with tuples as values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary. I would like to have pid be the key and the remaining two columns be values within the tuples.

I have tried `aggregated_events.set_index('pid').to_dict('list')` and `aggregated_events.set_index('pid').to_dict()` but know I am missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Original Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwk8u.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. You have duplicate pid's, so what are you expecting the output to be? Please [edit] to add it. As well, please provide the input df as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), and include the bad output too, for completeness. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341), [mre], and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can first transpose your dataframe to get first column as new column names, something like this:

```
df = df.set_index('pid').T
```

Then you can use  `to_dict` to convert a dataframe to a dictionary.